# Pi 4B suddenly becomes unresponsive / dead

Tags: pi-4

I have a Raspberry Pi 4 Model B, 4GB, which has been more or less happily running (Pihole and Plex) since November 2021 (updated to Bullseye in April). Ethernet connection plus external SSD via USB. Factory power unit. No additional hardware components, and no recent software changes. It does a job and isn't messed around with.

A week ago, it suddenly - without any intervention - became unresponsive. The red power LED was solid, but everything else was off. No ethernet lights, no USB power, no HDMI signal. I don't think it's been overheating - the temperature recorded by PIHole has been consistent (e.g. 55-62 C).

Nothing has really improved since then. I have reseated the SD card many times, powered off and on, tried with cables in and out, SD card in and out, and the behaviour remains as follows:

- Red power LED is lit
- Green LED lights for a **split second** then goes off.
- Sometimes (1 time in 5?), after perhaps an hour, I return to find the activity light is solid green, but I haven't been able to hook up a monitor at this point as the device doesn't normally live anywhere near a screen and I would have to turn it off to move it (I am trying to recreate this right now...)
- In all cases, USB and Ethernet get **no power**, and HDMI cable gets **no signal** (on either channel).
- My router reports no WiFi or Ethernet connection
- If it's booted, I can't tell, as I have no connectivity to the device.

I just tried with a brand new SD card, formatted with Raspberry Pi Imager (latest), and the results are identical. I don't bother connecting the Ethernet and USB now, to keep things simple.

I have tried to follow https://forums.raspberrypi.com/viewtopic.php?t=58151#p1485558 but this particular LED combination doesn't appear.

It's surprising to think this might suddenly be bricked out of the blue.

---

**Update:** I've given the Pi up as bricked, and moved on (to a 2013 Dell).

Comment: I'd hook up a monitor and power on

Comment: I did mention above that there is nothing from HDMI. Since the incident I have not been able to capture anything on a screen, likewise no network connectivity or USB power, nothing but the red light and the single flicker of green

Comment: Follow the forums.raspberrypi.com boot sticky.  If that gets nowhere the Pi is dead.

Comment: No luck as yet. What are the possible reasons for it suddenly failing without any intervention tho?

Comment: sorry, missed that - guess `I haven't been able to hook up a monitor at this point as the device doesn't normally live anywhere near a screen` made me think otherwise -  take it you've tried both HDMI ports

Comment: No worries. Yep, both ports. I'm pretty much resigned to this being bricked now, and am just deciding whether or not to get a replacement Pi, but I'd still be interested / curious to see if this could somehow be brought back to life.